# Best way to convert natural language sentence into machine readable format?

Tags: java, python, nlp

I have a database of financial products which gets updated everyday from information that we obtain from a data vendor. These products contain an "exit load", which is like a fees for exiting an investment earlier than a stipulated time period, and that is stored as a string in a column.

An example of such an exit load that we have received from our data provider is: **"If redeemed/ switched on or before 365 days from the date of allotment: - Nil for redemption/ switch out of units upto 24% of the units allotted (the limit), 1% on redemption in excess of 24% of the limit stated above- Redemption of units would be done on First in First out Basis (FIFO) Nil thereafter"**

I need to be able to convert such a sentence into a formula that can be used by my applications. For example, the above sentence can be converted into something like: **"if units_redeemed > 24% && investment_duration < 365 days then exit_load = 1% else 0%"**

There are more than 1000 sentence variations of such types of exit loads.

How can this be done?

Comment: If the 1000 different combinations always combine the same chunks of words, you could try to match those chunks and assign them the formula version of it. If the numbers within the chunks change from sentence to sentence you could treat them as a wildcard and match only the text, and then parse the numbers once you identified the chunks. Remember to trim for whitespaces and ignore case sensitivity. If the sentences are completely differently written I'm afraid you will have a very hard time getting this to work. Try and see if you can identify the repeatable patterns first.